# Running full-screen video on click for mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, html, video, mobile

Is possible to run (on Android/iOS) full screen youtube video on click on a link? I don't want click on a player. For example: clicking on [url](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sM2D3BkoRM0) will open video on full screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new activity with a VideoView in it. VideoView accepts video links (they say it can play rtsp, which is what youtube mobile is using, but I have yet to try)

just do `videoView.setVideoUri(rtsp://...);`