# HTML5 video full screen on mobile browsers (android)

Tags: android, html, html5-video, fullscreen

After a huge research I didn't find any answer to my question yet. I wanted to achieve my goal with **FullScreenAPI** but it is not supported in any mobile browser (except Firefox 19 and Blackberry browser - but I need a cross-browser solution). [Here's the source](http://caniuse.com/fullscreen). I also tested **FullScreenAPI** on native android browser and mobile Chrome with appropriately prefixed fullscreen functions. Each function was of type `undefined`.

Another approach was the **rtsp protocol** which is usually handled by an outer player. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9371037/1069604) is the guy who assumes that m.youtube.com uses that solution - I think it is not true (maybe the answer is outdated). Youtube uses native video's fullscreen. On mobile Chrome when you tap the play button, the movie instantly goes fullscreen.

Although, every source I *googled* tells me that native fullscreen is not possible on android browsers, still **HTML5 video element with its native controls** gives us a fullscreen button which works perfectly out there.

Since I don't want the native controls, can anyone share any ingenious solution to `How to trigger HTML5 video fullscreen button's`**`event`**?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a popup at 100% width/height with a close button on absolute on it playing your HTML5 video.

Old, simple and dirty trick... But works

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to share this possibility in the question. Unfortunately it is not a solution for me :( I need to trigger that very fullscreen from the native button (or, if it's not possible, I need to be 100% sure).

Answer (score 1):

all you need to work on "webkitbeginfullscreen" and "webkitendfullscreen" events for mobile devices, i think.it will

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>video</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function videoControl() {
    var myVideo = document.getElementById('myVideo');
    myVideo.addEventListener("webkitbeginfullscreen", enteringFullscreen, false);
    myVideo.addEventListener("webkitendfullscreen", exitingFullscreen, false);
}

function enteringFullscreen() {
    alert("entering full-screen mode");
}

function exitingFullscreen() {
    alert("exiting full-screen mode");
}
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="videoControl()">
 <div id="videoContainer">
 <video id="myVideo" src="myVideo.m4v" autoplay controls>
 </video>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try video.webkitEnterFullscreen() in a user interactive event handler(ex: click)

Answer (score 0):

Most people facing this issue is because the HTML5 video is implemented inside `<iframe>`.

Add the three attributes in iframe to enable fullscreen in adroid chrome
`<iframe allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true">`

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I use that should pretty much work everywhere:

```
function toggleFullScreen() {
  var doc = window.document;
  var elem = doc.body; //the element you want to make fullscreen

  var requestFullScreen = elem.requestFullscreen || elem.webkitRequestFullScreen || elem.mozRequestFullScreen || elem.msRequestFullscreen;
  var cancelFullScreen = doc.exitFullscreen || doc.webkitExitFullscreen || doc.mozCancelFullScreen|| doc.msExitFullscreen;

  if(!(doc.fullscreenElement || doc.mozFullScreenElement || doc.webkitFullscreenElement || doc.msFullscreenElement)) {
      requestFullScreen.call(doc.body);
  }
  else {
    cancelFullScreen.call(doc);
  }
}
```

Comment: This makes the webpage full screen, not just the element or video.